# Abseil LOG output printed twice in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, abseil

I have created a simple project which uses Abseil and is built and run inside of Qt Creator.

When I use any abseil logging, I see the output twice in the Qt Creator "Application Output" pane. Once in red and once again in white (I'm using dark theme). Using `std::cout`, I see the output once as white, as expected. Using `std::cerr`, I see the output once as red, as expected. I cannot figure out how to stop Abseil logging from printing twice. If I run the same process from the command line, the Abseil logs are only printed to stderr, as expected.

- OS: Windows 10
- Qt Creator versions tested: 11 & 12
- Qt version: 6.2.4 MSVC2019 64bit

Abseil is recently cloned locally as a subdirectory. The commit is `2a636651729cec997a433ce8e363c6344130944e`, though it happens with older versions too.

Here is the directory structure:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- CMakeLists.txt.user
|-- abseil-cpp
`-- main.cpp
```

Here is my main:

```
#include <absl/log/globals.h>
#include <absl/log/initialize.h>
#include <absl/log/log.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  absl::InitializeLog();
  absl::SetStderrThreshold(absl::LogSeverityAtLeast::kInfo);
  std::cout << "Cout test" << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "Cerr test" << std::endl;
  LOG(INFO) << "test";
  return 0;
}
```

This program will print something like:

```
Cout test
Cerr test
I0104 17:58:48.312991   20796 main.cpp:12] test
I0104 17:58:48.312991   20796 main.cpp:12] test
```

("Cerr test" and one of the "main.cpp:12] test" lines are red)

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.4)

project(main LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  main.cpp
)

set(ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD ON)
add_subdirectory(abseil-cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
PUBLIC
  absl::log
  absl::log_initialize
)
```

Comment: The log writes to stdout. `absl::SetStderrThreshold(absl::LogSeverityAtLeast::kInfo);` this duplicates logs in stderr.

Comment: That's not true. Abseil logging only outputs to stderr unless you register another `LogSink`. If I remove that line, I see no output from the abseil log lines. Also, if that were true, I should also see the output twice when I run the program from the command line.

Comment: *I cannot figure out how to stop Abseil logging from printing twice* It's not a problem with Abseil  nor with your code, but with how Qt Creator "improves" console output. It's a bug in Qt Creator, and I don't recall any knobs that can be tweaked to work around it, although I may be wrong. I'd hope the fix wouldn't be too involved, so if you wish to build Qt Creator yourself, you'd have a chance of fixing it :)

Comment: Right, Kuba. Thanks. I'm going to file a bug against Qt Creator.

Comment: Asked in the Qt forum, confirmed that it is probably a bug: https://forum.qt.io/topic/153507/abseil-log-output-printed-twice-in-qt-creator Filed a bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-30163

Answer (score 0):

This has been determined to be a bug in Qt Creator. I have come up with a workaround. I've created my own "Log Sink" and registered it with abseil.

```
class MyLogSink : public absl::LogSink {
public:
  void Send(const absl::LogEntry& entry) override {
    std::cerr << entry.text_message_with_prefix_and_newline();
  }
};
absl::LogSink *mySink = new MyLogSink;
absl::AddLogSink(mySink);
```

Additionally, the `LogSeverity` level ought to be set to a maximum to disable the usual absl logging.

```
absl::SetStderrThreshold(absl::LogSeverityAtLeast::kInfinity);
```